# Trying to dry up code - Variable is not passing to a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to dry up code for a couple of reports.

I took the table header code and put that in a partial. That works fine when I call that with a render partial. However, when I try to move the code for the body of the table, I am getting a 'something went wrong' error.

My original code that works is

```
<% @complaints.each do |complaint| %>
  <% if complaint.product_name == $complaint_group_name then %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to complaint.id, complaint  %></td>
      <td style="text-align: right;"><%= complaint.length %></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><%= complaint.disposition %></td>
      <td width="20%"><%= complaint.sales_order %></td>
        . . . 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The code that is not working is when I've moved that to a partial and try to render a partial

```
<% @complaints.each do |complaint| %>
  <% if complaint.product_name == $complaint_group_name then %>
    <%= render :partial => 'report_body' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I see an error of

```
I, [2016-07-12T10:25:09.046754 #95324]  INFO -- :   Rendered complaints/report_by_product.html.erb within layouts/application (359.4ms)
I, [2016-07-12T10:25:09.046754 #95324]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 375ms (ActiveRecord: 140.6ms)
F, [2016-07-12T10:25:09.046754 #95324] FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `complaint' for #<#<Class:0x51caab8>:0x95242f8>):
    1: 
    2: 
    3:         <tr>
    4:           <td><%= link_to complaint.id, complaint  %></td>
    5:           <td style="text-align: right;"><%= complaint.length %></td>
    6:           <td style="text-align: center;"><%= complaint.disposition %></td>
    7:           <td width="20%"><%= complaint.sales_order %></td>
  app/views/complaints/_report_body.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_complaints__report_body_html_erb__209592603_78833796'
```

Apparently the |complaint| part of the block does not get recognized by the partial. I either need to be able to pass this or include it in the partial - but then it gets messy because the grouping for each report would need to be handled in the partial.

The short question is can I pass |complaint| to the partial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass 'complaint' as a local variable to partial:

```
render partial: 'report_body', locals: { complaint: complaint }
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use short form like this

```
<%= render 'report_body', complaint: complaint %>
```

which is equivalent to

```
<%= render partial: 'report_body', locals: { complaint: complaint } %>
```